# Oracle database patch update doubts

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, upgrade

Oracle Recommended Patches -- Oracle Database (Doc ID 756671.1) says the following 4 patches are recommended to be applied to 11.2.0.4 database.

Note:21744343.8 Combo of 11.2.0.4.5 OJVM PSU and 11.2.0.4.8 DB PSU (Oct 2015)

Note:21555791.8 Oracle JavaVM Component 11.2.0.4.5 Database PSU (Oct 2015) (OJVM PSU)

Note:21352635.8 11.2.0.4.8 (Oct 2015) Database Patch Set Update (DB PSU)

Note:19852360.8 Oracle JavaVM Component 11.2.0.4.1 Database PSU - Generic JDBC Patch (Oct 2014)

I have a newly installed 11.2.0.4 database with absolutely no patches applied on it.

Now should I go ahead and apply all the above mentioned recommended patches on the database? or should I apply any previously released patches before applying these?

If yes, is there an order in which the above patches is to be applied?

Also, I will be applying the above patches through OEM12c, is there anything I should take care in doing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download only the combo patch - in essence it is the two other - DB and OJVM patches bundled in one archive. After that the patching sequence is as follows:

1. Apply the DB PSU, but do not run any post-install steps
2. Apply the Java PSU
3. Run the Java PSU post-install steps
4. Run the DB PSU post-install steps

Take a look at the following support note:

Oracle Recommended Patches -- "Oracle JavaVM Component Database PSU" (OJVM PSU) Patches (Doc ID 1929745.1)

In it is more detailed information about the OJVM patches.

Comment: I'm anyways going to use OEM to apply the patches so it will take care of the process I guess.

Comment: If you can, I'd suggest doing the patching "by hand".  It gives you a much better idea of what's going on.  After you know what OEM is going to be doing, then use OEM but if you don't understand the process, it's more advantageous to you to "get your hands dirty".

Answer (score 0):

Install the first one, that is a combo patch that includes the latest versions of all the others. The others are just the seperate PSU or OJVM patches.